# registering first date the app is launched

Tags: android, date, sharedpreferences, alarmmanager

I am developing an android app and I need to do something every month since the app is launched for the first time it is launched, the app will notify the user. how should i keep only the first date?

i used

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    final int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), day + "\n" + month,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but it changes every time i run the app.

any better ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Since you tagged this as "sharedpreferences", surely you know about the Preferences API, which is a good candidate for storing the "first date"? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html

Comment: Store it in sharedpreferences. When the app opens it should look for the date, and if it is not there, it is probably the first time it is being opened on that device.

Comment: you need to store it in a place where the user can not have authority over..with shared preference and internal data the user has authority over that, and could always bypass you...use an online database..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SharedPreferences. It will not allow you to store an Date object directly, but you can store a long which you can use for saving the date.getTime() value which represents the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

This is an example Activity that demonstrates this.

```
public class MyDateActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public static final String PREFS_LONG_DATE_FIRST_RUN = "FirstRun";

    private Date firstRunDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
        super.onCreate(state);

        // Restore preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        if (settings.contains(PREFS_LONG_DATE_FIRST_RUN)) {
            // Found date in settings
            long dateFirstRun = settings.getLong(PREFS_LONG_DATE_FIRST_RUN, 0);
            firstRunDate = new Date(dateFirstRun);
        } else {
            // First time running
            firstRunDate = new Date();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();

        // Get preferences
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

        // Only write the first run date if settings don't contain a first run date.
        if (!settings.contains(PREFS_LONG_DATE_FIRST_RUN)) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putLong(PREFS_LONG_DATE_FIRST_RUN, new Date().getTime());
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}
```